# Cambiar valor fuera del scope

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo una función que retorna un arreglo con 2 valores y los desestructuro. La función recibe un `string`, el cual dentro de la función, lo retorna en `varOriginal`. Y el segundo valor del arreglo es una función a la cual le paso un string `"Silla"` y el `valorOriginal` debe cambiar a `"Silla"` luego de apretar un botón. El tema es que no funciona porque no se manejar el scope.

```
const [varOriginal, varFuncion] = funcionCambiante("Mesa");
```

En resumen: Al apretar el botón, quiero que la variable `varOriginal` devuelva el valor que le mande por la otra función, en este caso `"Silla"`. Adjunto mi código:

```js
const funcionCambiante = original => {
  let primerValor = original;
  //Funcion que cambia variable
  const cambioVariable = segundoValor => {
    primerValor = segundoValor;
  };
  return [primerValor, cambioVariable];
};

//Desestructuro la funcion.
const [varOriginal, varFuncion] = funcionCambiante('Mesa');
console.log(varOriginal);
const cambiarValor = () => {
  varFuncion('Silla');
  console.log(varOriginal); //Sigue devolviendo Mesa y no Silla
};
```

```html
<button onclick="cambiarValor()">Cambiar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

puede hacerlo asi:

```js
const funcionCambiante = original => {
  let primerValor = original;
  //Funcion que cambia variable
  const cambioVariable = segundoValor => {
    primerValor = segundoValor;
    return [primerValor, cambioVariable];
  };
  return [primerValor, cambioVariable];
};

//Desestructuro la funcion.

let [varOriginal, varFuncion] = funcionCambiante('Mesa');
console.log(varOriginal);
const cambiarValor = () => {
  // reasignamos
  [varOriginal, varFuncion] = varFuncion('Silla');
  console.log(varOriginal); //Sigue devolviendo Mesa y no Silla
};
```

```html
<button onclick="cambiarValor()">Cambiar</button>
```

Comment: Hola Bryro, tu respuesta es solo código, te sugiero que la edites, explicando como funciona tu código y los errores cometidos por el OP, de esa manera, no solo evitarás recibir votos negativos, sino que tu respuesta será más útil.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy tan segura de lo que deseas hacer pero... VarOriginal la estás declarando como constante y nunca le estás cambiando el valor. Si quieres usar esa variable para mostrar los cambios, debes declarar como variable con 'let' y hacer algo como esto.. Asignando el resultado de la función que cambia la variable.

```js
const funcionCambiante = original => {
  let primerValor = original;
  //Funcion que cambia variable
  const cambioVariable = segundoValor => {
    primerValor = segundoValor;
    return primerValor;
  };
  return [primerValor, cambioVariable];
};

//Desestructuro la funcion.
let [varOriginal, varFuncion] = funcionCambiante('Mesa');
console.log(varOriginal); // Devuelve Mesa
const cambiarValor = () => {
  varOriginal = varFuncion('Silla');
  console.log(varOriginal); // Devuelve Silla
};

cambiarValor() // llamas a la función en tu botón
```